# Is there an easy way to create this ndarray/tensor numpy/torch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a python list `foo: list[list[int]]` where the int values are between 0 and 100. I want a pytorch tensor `bar` of shape (n, 100) where `n = len(foo)` which satisfies

`bar[i, j] = 1` if `j in foo[i]` else `bar[i, j] = 0`.

Does anyone know a computationally fast way to do this in pytorch. Here is an example:

```
foo = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
bar = torch.tensor(
    [
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, ..., 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0],
    ]
)
```

Given a list of the form foo, I want a tensor of the form bar. My current implemenation is

```
foo = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
bar = torch.stack(
    [
        torch.sum(
            F.one_hot(item, num_classes=100),
            dim=0,
        )
        for item in foo
    ]
)
```

But it is too slow for my purpose.

Comment: Can you please include a small example to test the code in a simpler way?

Comment: The problem is that `foo` has each sublist of a different length and pytorch does not play nice with that, maybe you could try padding foo so that each sublist has the length of the longest sublist and go from there?

Comment: `out = np.zeros((n,N), dtype='int'); for i, t in enumerate(foo): out[i,t]=1`

Answer (score 1):

Does a `numpy`-based solution work for you?

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

foo = [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
bar = np.zeros(shape=(len(foo), 100))

for i, items in enumerate(foo):
    for item in items:
        bar[i, item] = 1

bar = torch.tensor(bar)
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion. It has about the same execution time as my approach though. I think if I could skip the double for loop it would be fast enough.

Comment: Actually it's possible to directly index by `items` (thus removing the inner loop) but it's 8x slower: e.g. `bar[i, items]=1`

Comment: I actually made a mistake in my memory of how you can slice tensors. I think your answer is optimal. Thanks.

Comment: If `items` is a large numpy array (i.e. `foo` is list of arrays), then `bar[i,items]=1` is faster.  For for smallish lists (<1000?) the double loop is faster.